# How can I set application permissions for Office 365 Unified API?

Tags: office365

I want to create a (php) web application where the calendar entries for a specific office 365 user is shown. One should be able to visit the site and see these entries, without having to log in.

My company does not yet have a azure subscription, so i created one with my hotmail address (in case this is relevant).

When researching how to do this, I keep seeing references to setting *Application Permissions* to *Office 365 Exchange Online*, such as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365 under *Defining permissions*.

I've registered a web application in Azure AD, and uploaded a x509 certificate in the manifest. When I try to add Application Permissions to read calendar entries, all I can find is *Office 365 unified API (preview)*, which has **no** Application permissions!

[image: Permissions to other applications]

In the *Delegated Permissions* for *Office 365 unified API (preview)* I find the equivalent of what I'm looking for, namely the setting *Read signed-in user's calendars*. But as I understand, service/daemon applications need application permissions, not delegated permissions.

TL;DR: I want my service/daemon app to access user's calendars. I cannot find any application permissions available for office 365 unified api (preview), and office 365 exchange online does not exist in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 Unified API doesn't yet support service/daemon app access but we are really close to supporting it.  In the mean time, you can use Outlook APIs to accomplish your scenario.  The endpoint is https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0.  When you register your app, add application permissions (read or read/write based on your scenarios) as shown in the picture.  That should enable you to use client credential flow to access other user's calendars.

[image]

Comment: My problem was actually that I was using a azure subscription with my hotmail account. Therefore I did not have the Office 365 Exchange Online application in my list of applications to set permissions to. I found this out when I was allowed to start playing on the azuresubscription of my employer.

Anyway, thank you for answering! Good to hear that the unified api also will support service/daemon app access soon!

Answer (score 0):

So, the *Office 365 Exchange Online* application i wanted my service/daemon application have rights to (Calendar.read and Calendar.write) don't ship with Azure by default. To get it, I need to subscribe to it (the business subscription, not home):

[image: Office 365 Exchange Online]

The *Office 365 Unified API* does ship with Azure, but as [Venkat Ayyadevara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846196/venkat-ayyadevara-msft) says, this application does not support daemon/service apps (yet!).